# Правильно ли говорить "на выходных"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Иностранец, изучающий русский, пишет: **"На выходных я хожу в кино"**. Мой слух этим оскорбляется. Я бы сказал "**по выходным**" или, на худой конец, "**в выходные**".

Прав ли мой слух, оскорбляясь таким выражением? Если да, то есть ли какое-то формальное правило, подтверждающее правоту моего слуха?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком предложении выражение "на выходных" употребить невозможно, оно не сочетается с "регулярной основой" действий (хожу). Само по себе выражение корректно и легко находится во множестве книг, оно обычно ссылается на *отдельную* пару или группу выходных (ближайшие, последние, следующие подходящие - с разной степенью определённости). В отличие от "(уехать) на выходные", "работа в выходные", оно подразумевает использование (для названного занятия) неполного отрезка времени в пределах выходных.

> Как-нибудь на выходных найду время сходить к зубному (в кино и т. п.).

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса (ошибка?): Вообще, без «Свободы» сразу становится непонятно, который час, где штаны и кто я такой. Это каждый рабочий может заметить по себе на выходных. «Свобода» как-то дисциплинирует. [Ксения Букша. Завод «Свобода» // «Новый мир», 2013]

Comment: И еще: А хмурые и не интересующиеся в жизни ничем, кроме как набить брюхо, выпить и оттянуться на выходных, делаются в спокойной, скучной обстановке, так что родители даже обычно не догадываются, какое именно соитие в результате обернулось их отпрыском. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)]

Comment: Максимус никогда не отличался особенным энтузиазмом, работал от звонка до звонка и уходил, как только стрелка часов вставала на заветную цифру «6», а на выходных отключал мобильный телефон или просто не отвечал на звонки со службы. [Герман Садулаев. Таблетка (2008)] ------- **и еще, и еще**........

Comment: "Грамота" и вовсе считает "на выходных" просторечием и на вопросы о всех случаях его употребления всякий раз отвечает одной и той же фразой. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85 Не могу с такими ответами согласиться, но и процитированных сочинителей не хочется защищать.

Comment: @М_Г Я бы не стал предлагать "оттянуться на выходных" в качестве доказательства литературной нормы. Даже если это попало в Нацкорпус (там ещё и не такое попадается).

Comment: @grizzly Я привел все эти примеры не в качестве доказательства, а для обсуждения.

Answer (score 2):

1) В этой теме важно различать значения **неопределенного предложного падежа и определенного винительного  падежа.**

**На выходных**  (в ближайшие выходные дни, в один из дней) я собираюсь сходить в кино.

Но: **В  выходной** (в конкретный выходной день, субботу или воскресенье) я собираюсь пойти в кино.

Правильно: ***По выходным дням (в выходные дни) я хожу в кино.***  Здесь настоящее время, **определенное** повторяющееся действие, поэтом В.п. или П.п.

2) Можно сравнить с наречием ***на днях***: 1. В один из ближайших дней; в ближайшее время, очень скоро. 2. Несколько дней назад; совсем недавно. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188749/На](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188749/%D0%9D%D0%B0)

3) Другие примеры

Различаются по форме следующие выражения: **На выходных** поедем на дачу (точное время  не указано, П.п.). **На выходные** собираемся (планируем)  поехать на дачу (на два выходных дня, В.п.).

4) Вообще говоря, это выражение не то чтобы просторечное, но оно **так часто употребляется неправильно,** что уже кажется просторечным.

Наречие ***на выходных***, как и наречие **на днях**,  **должно иметь значение неопределенности** (в один из ближайших или уже прошедших выходных), и оно относится к будущему или прошедшему, но только не к настоящему времени.

5) **Неверно (из приводимых примеров):**

это каждый  может заметить по себе **на выходных**;

не интересующиеся в жизни ничем, кроме как набить брюхо, выпить и оттянуться **на выходных**;

а **на выходных** отключал мобильный телефон или просто не отвечал на звонки со службы.

Здесь нет неопределенности, но есть повторяемость, периодичность действий.

Вот еще пример неправильного употребления слова: ***МЧС просит горожан оставаться дома на выходных*.** Правильно: *МЧС просит горожан оставаться дома в выходные дни.*